# How to filter for a single object based on multiple instances of another object?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to create a query to find renters that match at least one of a set of floorplans and need help writing the query.

The Renter model

```
class RenterProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    desired_location = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    move_in_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, help_text='Use mm/dd/yyyy format')
    coordinates =models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    lat = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    lng = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    numbers = (('0','0'),('1','1'),('2','2'),('3','3'),('4','4'),('5','5'),('6+','6+'),)    
    beds = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True, choices=numbers)
    baths = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True, choices=numbers)
```

The FloorPlan Model

```
class FloorPlan(models.Model):
    property_name = models.ForeignKey(Property)
    floor_plan_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    numbers = (('0','0'),('1','1'),('2','2'),('3','3'),('4','4'),('5','5'),('6+','6+'),)
    bedrooms = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True, choices=numbers)
    bathrooms = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True, choices=numbers)
    sqft = models.IntegerField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    min_price = models.IntegerField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    max_price = models.IntegerField(max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)
    availability = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True, help_text='Use mm/dd/yyyy format')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='floor_plans/', null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: I suggest you to provide an example with sample data and what you need to get as a result

Comment: Agree with Serj. A minimal working example that gives a sense of the issue will be the best.

Comment: @Serj Ok, never done that.  What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Simply provide some sample data (use dic, or list) as input to your solution and another as output as you desire.

Comment: Agree with what the others said, but  alsojust looking at the two models, I don't see anything linking the two to each other, so I'm not sure how you even know a Renter has a FloorPlan.

Comment: @onyeka renter doesn't have a floor plan.  Looking for renters that would like one of a property's floorplan

Comment: Based on what? Price? Beds? Baths? That kind of thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function like below:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def get_floor_plan(renter_profile):
   '''
   It will take RenterProfile model class's object as input.
   It will return a FloorPlan Queryset with desired matches of properties
   '''
   return FloorPlan.objects.filter(Q(bedrooms=renter_profile.beds)|(Q(maxprice__lte=renter_profile.price)&Q(min_price__gte=renter_profile.price))|Q(availability__lte=renter_profile.move_in_date))
```